# How to highlight a ListView item using OnLongClickListener from custom Adapter class in Android

Tags: android, listview, adapter, highlight, onlongclicklistener

Here's what I want to do:

In my main Activity I have a ListView with a custom Adapter because my ListView item should contain a TextView AND a CheckBox. When I do a long press on an item, I wanna use a contextual action mode in the ActionBar and HIGHLIGHT the selected ListView item.

Here's what I did:

I followed this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#listadvanced_interactive) for the custom Adapter and this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#tutorial_contextualmenu) for the ActionMode. Both is working fine. I'm able to interact with my database underlying my adapter and ListView. I should mention that I implemented everything for the ActionMode in my custom adapter class.

Here's what is NOT working:

I can't figure out how to highlight the selected ListView item although I'm able to delete the database entry corresponding to the content of the TextView in the ListView item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution myself. I took a few different steps:

Code-related steps:

1. I moved everything ActionMode related code from my adapter class to my activity class. Before that I triggered the action mode by using an OnLongClickListener on my TextView in my ListView item because at that point I didn't know how to make the TextView's text available for the ActionMode (I want to be able to delete it by clicking an icon in the ActionBar). When you use a CLickListener on one of the ListView items it kinda "blocks" the OnClickListener of the ListView item you set in your Activity. Don't do that!!!
2. I set an OnItemLongClickListener to my ListView in my Activity. From there I trigger the ActionMode AND save the text from the item's TextView like this (`itemNames` is a `List<String>` set to my adapter, `deleteString` is a class attribute of my Activity):

   `deleteString = itemNames.get(_postion);`

But these steps were only to get my code working as it is supposed to due to the changes I had to make via XML.

XML-related steps:

1. I had to remove the background attribute from my ListView item main layout
2. I had to add the following attributes to my outer row layout: `android:clickable="true"` and `android:longClickable="true"` (maybe longClickable is already enough, just to be sure ;-) )
3. I had to create an own selector drawable and set it as background to my ListView item layout: `android:background="@drawable/my_selector"`

This way I achieved the following:

- I have a ListView in my Activity with a custom layout (TextView + CheckBox) and a custom adapter
- I can use an OnCheckedChangeListener on the CheckBox
- I can activate ActionMode by doing a long click on my ListView item AND reach the TextView's content for further processes
- I get the default holo_blue_light background highlight on my ListView item when I click on it (I use Holo Theme Light with Dark Action Bar for my App)

The only thing that I didn't get to work via XML was to keep my ListView item highlighted while the ActionMode was active, so I did that by doing this

```
_view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
```

in the OnItemLongClickListener of my ListView in my Activity class (don't forget to redraw or refresh your ListView in `onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode _mode)` of your `ActionMode.Callback`)

Voilà! I hope this might help some of you! Took me a few days and LOTS of research.

Here my code examples for my ListView item layout and my selector layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:longClickable="true" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp" >
    </CheckBox>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingListItemName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkBox"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <color android:color="#00000000" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: I only had to add android:background="@drawable/my_selector", create the selector.xml and that's it. It worked for me doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

you can set android:state_activated=true in your background drawable of your list row layout

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_activated="true">
    <layer-list >
        <!-- <item >
            <color android:color="#ff00aa00"/>
        </item> -->

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#aa58BAED"/>
                <corners android:radius="3px"/>
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
<item >
    <color android:color="#00000000"/>
</item>
</selector>
```

But it will work only for android api > Api 11

Comment: Tried it, but unfortunately this doesn't work for me. The thing is, that my ListView doesn't behave as let's say the default ListView of a ListActivity, meaning that it doesn't even get highlighted by a normal click. I have no idea how to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I was faced with the same problem i.e wanted to highlight my list view items on click and long click. This works for me.
[Android Multi Choice Mode Listener with Custom Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235805/android-multi-choice-mode-listener-with-custom-adapter)

Comment: Can you add a synopsis of the link in case it disappears?

Comment: Add android:background="?android:activatedBackgroundIndicator"to your parent LinearLayout(of each list) to  produce a highlighted background upon selection.